# macOS: library not found for -lpaho-mqtt3c

Tags: c, macos, gcc, linker, paho

What I have done:

```
git clone https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.c
cd paho.mqtt.c
make
sudo make install
```

Then, I tried compiling a simple C program that includes the MQTT C library like this:

```
#include <MQTTClient.h>
```

The command I used was:

```
$ gcc -o mqttTest mqttTest.c -lpaho-mqtt3c
```

What I got was ...
[image]
... even though the libraries are clearly present in /usr/local/lib:
[image]
What do I need to do to compile my code?

I already tried adding -L/usr/local/lib to the compile command, to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer on GitHub. See VilleViktor's post here: https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.cpp/issues/150

All I had to do was:

```
$ mv /usr/local/lib/libpaho-mqtt3a.so.1.0 /usr/local/lib/libpaho-mqtt3a.so.1
$ mv /usr/local/lib/libpaho-mqtt3as.so.1.0 /usr/local/lib/libpaho-mqtt3as.so.1
$ mv /usr/local/lib/libpaho-mqtt3c.so.1.0 /usr/local/lib/libpaho-mqtt3c.so.1
$ mv /usr/local/lib/libpaho-mqtt3cs.so.1.0 /usr/local/lib/libpaho-mqtt3cs.so.1
```

Maybe that saves someone else a lot of time on Google ...